# How To Add Two Probabilities To Find Total Probabilities

Tags: probability

When I meet a friend playing SimCity on Tuesday, I have a 62% chance of buying the game.
When I meet another friend playing SimCity on Wednesday, I have a 84% chance of buying the game.

I need to find the total probability that I buy Simcity.

But when I add 62% to 84% that makes 146% which I am pretty sure is wrong. So how do I find the total probability in this case?

Comment: You need to consider that if you buy SimCity on Tuesday, you won't buy it on Wednesday.

Comment: The question implicitly assumes what Jerry says.

Comment: So would I have to add 62% to 38%*84% which is 0.62 + 0.3192 = 0.9392 is that correct? @Jerry

Comment: @JimmyNeutronFan4Eva : That's it!

Comment: Ok thanks. Your comment got me on the right track to understanding the problem better, so I appreciate it. @Jerry